# How to print a concatened sentence?

Tags: javascript

I am doing an exercise on concatenation.

I have a doubt, I have to print this sentence from Shakespeare "to be or nor to be".

```js
var sentence1 = 'to be';
var sentence2 = 'or not';
console.log(sentence1 + ' ' + ' ' + sentence2 + ' ' + sentence1);
```

But it gives me an error:

> Code is incorrect
> The first string should be 'to be'

What seems to be the problem?

Comment: What are you using to get that error? How does it know what the "first string" is?

Comment: ``to be  or not to be`` is what I am getting. What's wrong with that?

Comment: show the full task description

Comment: I am doing an exercise, I am learning code:

Use the strings available in the given variables to produce and print the famous Shakesperean quote (remember: spaces are characters too).

These are the instructions.

Comment: @Zephirus are you using a website/app? Where does this code get executed/run? How does it check the code?

Comment: it looks like some automated test failing. Maybe you have to give a specific name to the first string, rather than `sentence1`, or they are wanting you to concat on an string rather than just outputting it to the console

Comment: btw, I voted to close as the OP has said it was a typo

Comment: I'd still like to know what you are using. What learning tool do you use that gives tasks and throws errors like that?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the ES6 template literals to make it more cleaner, Try this:

```js
const sentence1 = 'to be';
const sentence2 = 'or not';
console.log(`${sentence1} ${sentence2} ${sentence1}`);
```

Comment: This is definitely what I'd suggest, but this also doesn't answer the question. (Why there is an error)

Comment: I should've added it as a comment, but I cannot do that since I don't have 50 reputations. So I thought to help him with the template literals.

Comment: It is annoying when you cannot comment. This is a good suggestion, but it's not an answer. (also I didn't downvote btw)

Comment: Exactly. So annoying.